# Iterate over protected variables in a php class

Tags: php, oop, iterator, protected

I have had difficulty finding any guides on this so I thought I'd ask here.

I have objects, those objects all have protected variables. Those variables are protected because I want them readable, but only some of them writable and I want to filter them when they get set. To accomplish this I created the following class, from which all other classes that fit this design extend:

```
abstract class UnitObject{
    protected $setables = [];

    abstract public function filter($value);

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if ( in_array($name, $this->setables) ) {   
            $this->{$name} = $this->filter($value);
        } else {
            /*
             * Log something
             */
        }
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->{$name};
    }
}
```

Now this is accomplishing the desired result. I would, however, like to have these protected variables be accessible via a foreach loop to iterate over the properties of the object. As they are not "visible" in the traditional sense the default code does not seem to work for this. After some research I have discovered that I can implement Iterator  to accomplish something like this, but all of the examples are if I implemented it on the specific object.

My goal is to implement iterator on my "UnitObject" that my children inherit from, and write the required methods so they will property rotate through all variables on that object when a foreach loop is used. So my questions are as follows:

1. Is implementing iterator the best technique to solve this problem?
2. Is it possible to use an abstract parent class that implements Iterator and have that class contain the functions required, or will I need to create the required functions for each specific object?
3. Finally, if it is possible, could you provide an example, or direct me to a source that has a good example?

Thanks!

Comment: Just crate proper setters like a grown up, instead of abusing the black hole of complexity, that are magic `__set` and `__get`. Also, suffix "object" is .. emm ... questionable choice.

Comment: Ask  yourself if you really **need** this complexity. Why not just have a function that returns the variables as an array?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately this functionality is required. This is part of a framework that is being developed for a much larger system. Using the magic functions allows the scope to be controlled without having to write getters and setters for hundreds of distinct variables.

Comment: You have three different questions, and you should have only one (otherwise is too broad). You are asking about the "best technique", and that is an opinion based question. (Also off topic). And question three asks for an offsite resource (also off-topic).

Answer (score 0):

ryantxr, thanks you actually were pretty close to what I needed to do. I found a solution after becoming more competent with the iterator implementation. Here is the code I added to my UnitObject abstract class:

```
    /*
     * Functions to allow protected and private variables to be iterated over
     */

    private $variablePosition = 0;
    private $variableArray = [];

    public function rewind() 
    {
        $this->variableArray = array_keys(get_object_vars($this));
        $this->variablePosition = 0;
    }

    public function current() 
    {
        return $this->{$this->key()};
    }

    public function key() 
    {
        return $this->variableArray[$this->variablePosition];
    }

    public function next() 
    {
        ++$this->variablePosition;
    }

    public function valid() 
    {           
        return isset($this->variableArray[$this->variablePosition]);
    }

*Note: I also had to implement Iterator on my UnitObject class
```

This now allows for my objects that extend my abstract class to iterate over protected variables.